# Android studio 2.0 emulator vs real device margins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm using Galaxy A5 as a main testing device for my Android app. In addition, I defined the same device spec. avd in avd manager (the same screen size, resolution, platform version number, etc.). However, some margins for activity layout are not drawn the same on the device and emulator. How can i fix this?

An example of margin not drawn correctly (marginTop="-20dp", marginBottom="-22dp"):

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/logo_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/logo_margin_bottom"/>
```

Comment: You should add some screenshots to see the difference

Comment: Top margin is not the same. I.e., this image is little bit higher on the emulator than on the device.

Comment: not matter what, before you release your app, test it in real devices!